# Can't send data with the use of POST request from Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, networking

I am trying to send data from Java code to PHP code with the use of a POST request. For some reason on the PHP side I get nothing at all, but my code "works" (no exception occurs). What can be the problem? Thanks in advance!
My data looks something like this:

```
"data=" + sb.toString()
```

And the code can be found here below:

```
public static void sendRequest(String encryptedString) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;

    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost/something/function").openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(encryptedString.length());

        dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(encryptedString);
        dos.flush();

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't create connection...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(dos != null) dos.close();
            if(connection != null) connection.disconnect();
            if(br != null) br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

PS: The picture:
[image: wireshark img]

Comment: The var_dump() PHP function returns the following: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>

Comment: You are not sending it to "PHP", but to a web server (presumably Apache), so you should check if the HTTP POST is arriving to Apache or not. Check its access log to verify that.

Comment: I know I am sending it to the webserver, but all I wanted to say is that I am trying to pass through data from Java code to PHP code. I will check the logs as soon as  I will have some time (if I can find them in this bloody wamp structure xD) though, thanks for the advice

Comment: I checked the logs, it says the POST goes through (200 OK). The problem must be on the PHP side then I think. Or maybe for some reason my Java code won't write the necessary data to the output stream.

Comment: Try to change the url with something like **http://www.google.com** , if its working then its from PHP

Comment: This `encryptedString.length()` to this `encryptedString.getBytes().length`.

Comment: With the help of WireShark I was able to catch the packet, and the thing is it is sending a wrong key / value pair. As you can see the key is sb.toString() part, and the data= part seems to be lost.
PS: I added the picture to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I encrypted the whole data=randomnumber thing with SHA-1. The data= part should not be encrypted and needs to be added later.